# How can i "reset" a variable (SUM(x) as Variable) in a MySQL nested Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have been managing to solve this MySQL-Riddle, and i think it is not clear yet for me.

I have a Table with the following structure (i.e):

```
    ID | Date                | Attr1 | Attr2 
    1  | 2018-01-31 12:00:00 |   5   |   7
    2  | 2018-01-31 12:10:00 |   4   |   3
    3  | 2018-01-31 12:20:00 |   0   |   7
    ...
    ...
    k  | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 |   4   |   5
    k+1| 2018-02-01 00:10:00 |   1   |   3
    ...
```

and so on...

I am trying to calculate SUM(Attr1) as S1, SUM(Attr2) as S2, and the diference between these values (S1-S2). I have achieved it by using the "Self-Inner Join" (as described [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/10/19/cumulative-sum-in-sql-server-/)).

The problem i have not solved yet is: i get the whole ( w h o l e ) SUM of the values, and i want to reset this S1 and S2 when the day changes. I have entries for several months, and doing it manually it would not be an good choice for me.

Do you have any advice? i am grateful for your messages and help. My SQL level is Beginner-Intermediate, and i do not remember how to do it.

Thank you so much for your help.

EDIT:

My expected output is

```
    ID | Date                | Attr1 | Attr2 | S1 | s2  |  S1 -S2
    1  | 2018-01-31 12:00:00 |   5   |   7   | 5  | 7   |  -2
    2  | 2018-01-31 12:10:00 |   4   |   3   | 9  | 10  |  -1
    3  | 2018-01-31 12:20:00 |   0   |   7   | 9  | 17  |  -8
    ...
    ...
    k  | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 |   4   |   5   | 4  | 5   | -1
    k+1| 2018-02-01 00:10:00 |   1   |   3   | 5  | 8   | -3
    ...
```

EDIT 2: i share what i have tried to do not succeeding:

```
    select t1.id, t1.date, t1.attr1, t1.attr2, 
           t2.id, t2.date, t2.attr1, t2.attr2,
           sum(t2.attr1) as cumAttr1,
           sum(t2.attr2) as cumAttr2,
    sum(t2.attr1) - sum(t2.attr2) as diffAttrs

    from table t1 
    inner join table t2 
    on t1.date >= t2.date

    group by t1.id, t1.attr1
    order by t1.date
```

With this i will get the whole group of rows with the sum of it, but i would like to reset the "sum" value every day.

Once again, i appreciate your feedback.

EDIT 2:

*I have realized, it is possible to obtain the same results with Stored Procedures and a little bit more order on my side (facepalm). It *is not* necessary trying to accomplish everything with a single SELECT*

Best regards, everybody. Thanks for everything!

Comment: you can use the group by date. This will sum olny the Attr1 or Attr2 for that day

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: What's the expected output based on the current example data?

Comment: i know Stack Overflow isn't a coding fabric ;) my question is which function or thing should i take into account or am missing... I have already added the expected output. I want for every new day to reset this sum S1 and S2...

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have already added the expected output. Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select date(date), sum(attr1), sum(attr2),
       sum(attr1) - sum(attr2) as diff
from t
group by date(date);
```

I don't see what a self-join has to do with this problem.

EDIT:

You seem to want the cumulative sum.  I would approach this for the overall problem as:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(tt1.attr1)
        from t tt1
        where tt1.date <= t.date
       ) as running_attr1,
       (select sum(tt2.attr2)
        from t tt2
        where tt2.date <= t.date
       ) as running_attr2
from t;
```

To restart on each day, you just add to the `where` clause:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(tt1.attr1)
        from t tt1
        where date(tt1.date) = date(t.date) and tt1.date <= t.date
       ) as running_attr1,
       (select sum(tt2.attr2)
        from t tt2
        where date(tt2.date) = date(t.date) and tt2.date <= t.date
       ) as running_attr2
from t;
```

Comment: i would give it a try. Thanks for the commment!

Comment: This did the trick! i think i had not seen the possibilities from the where clause. Thank you so much for your help.  T h a n k s ! ! !

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your original query, I can't be sure how close yours was; but this should be the simplest self-join query to get the results you've specified.

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Date, t.Attr1, t.Attr2
  , SUM(tPrev.Attr1) AS S1, SUM(tPrev.Attr2) AS S2  
  , SUM(tPrev.Attr1)-SUM(tPrev.Attr2) AS `S1 -S2`
FROM t AS t
LEFT JOIN t AS tPrev 
   ON DATE(t.Date) = DATE(tPrev.Date) -- Get records from the day of t
   AND tPrev.Date <= t.Date           -- But only ones earlier in the day, or t itself
GROUP BY t.ID, t.Date, t.Attr1, t.Attr2
;
```

Comment: this way would give us the results with the SUM() not being resseted after a new day on Date, right?

Comment: The sum should "reset" for each day; the key is that the join condition only picks prior (tPrev) records on the same date (or the "current", t, one), and it is those records that are actually being summed up. (I added some comment to the join conditions to better explain.)